# Android : Modify the timeout of "getInputStream"

Tags: java, android, sockets, connection, timeout

I created a new Socket and use it to communicate with a server :

```
mySocket = new Socket();
mySocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Network.SERVER_ADDRESS, Network.SERVER_PORT), (int) (3 * DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS));
mySocket.setSoTimeout(0);

try {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(mySocket.getInputStream()));
        MessageContent messageContent = (MessageContent) objectInputStream.readObject();
        Network._readMessage(context, messageContent);
    }
}
catch (Exception exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works fine. However when the server becomes unavailable, the following exception is raised after exactly 60 seconds :

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
```

This is a completely normal behavior. It's fine.
But by the way, my question is : How can I modify the timeout duration so that the ECONNRESET exception will be raised 3sec after a disconnection instead of 60sec?

Answer (score 0):

You can set desired Timeout using:

`mySocket.setSoTimeout(timeout_in_millis);`

But remember that Default timeout set by server is usually 2 minute so the server going to close socket after that no matter what timeout you set.

Comment: setSoTimeout doesn't affect the ECONNRESET exception raised when occurs a disconnection.

Comment: you mean that setting mySocket.setSoTimeout(3000); doesn't make socket to timeout after 3 second?